# How to invoke the method of a fragment that belongs to an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, reflection

With this code I am invoking a method of an activity.

What I require is to invoke a method of a fragment that belongs to an activity.

```
if (AppCompatActivity.class.equals(ctx.getClass().getSuperclass())) {
    if (callBackName != null) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) ctx;
        Method method = activity.getClass().getMethod(callBackName, parameters);
        method.invoke(activity, response, isError, errorType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the method (that you are invoking on activity as in your example) call the fragment method ..

in Fragment

```
public void iAmFragmentMethodInFragment() {
}
```

in Activity

```
public void iAmActivityMethodInActivity() {
 fragment.iAmFragmentMethodInFragment()
}
```